# A Flush() issue after Merging an Entity

Tags: java, orm, jpa, eclipselink

My problem is that I have an object A which contains a list of B Objects

```
@Entity
class A {

   @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.MERGE})
   List<B> list;

}
```

When I make a "merge" of an object A and then call "flush" inside a stateless EJB method

```
em.merge(a); //a is of class A
em.flush(); //doesn't flush "list"
```

it actually doesn't work. the ids of B objects of "list" are not set.

But persisting and flushing work

```
em.persist(a);
em.flush(); // it works!
```

The ids of B object of "list" are set.

I'm using EclipseLink. Does anybody know what could be happening?

Comment: Because of the noise in the answers below (some friends?), I wonder if the question is serious and until I get confirmation, I won't spend more time on it. If those people are your friends, you should educate them a bit.

Comment: This question is some sort of spam magnet.

Comment: @Pascal, @bmargulies; Cleaned and protected from further silliness.  Thanks for the flag.

Answer (score 0):

> it actually doesn't work because the ids of the B obects being part of the list "list" are not setted.

You should avoid using the id to implement `equals/hashCode`, the contract shouldn't change while objects are in the `List`. Anyway, I can't reproduce your problem with EclipseLink 2.0: a merge on `A` cascades an insert on `B` when I add a `B` to the list.